NSTableView dragImageForRowsWithIndexes: produces a blank image
When an NSTableView's draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle is set to NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap, the method dragImageForRowsWithIndexes:tableColumns:event:offset: returns an NSImage that appears to have the correct size, but it has no visible content (regardless of the offset argument).
So I cannot set an image for dragged rows at the beginning of a drag in tableView:draggingSession:willBeginAtPoint:forRowIndexes:. There is nothing I can show under the cursor.
The image appears correct with another draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle.
Any solution that would allow using the whole dragged row as the image component of a dragged item using NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap?
